# What identifiable variables can be collected via server/client connection logs( wireless AP's) to uniquely identify a device across networks?

Tags: privacy, wifi

For instance, the MAC address is one variable that stays the same across networks, along with Hostname, Operating System, and the combination of open ports/services. Ignoring browser specific identifiers, just the max that a wireless AP would be able to log, what else is there?

Comment: You will find this interesting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543419/bssid-vs-mac-address

Comment: Can you expand on your question? What control do you have over the network and devices? Are the devices controlled by the public or is this a corporate network and company-owned devices? Why do you want to uniquely identify devices? Over what networks?

Comment: I dont want to identify devices, im wondering how to avoid identification by essentially scrambling all variables everytime the device hits a network, however not all the variables are known to me. Mac, hostname, os, ports/services can all be spoofed on each new connection, but what other variables would need to be spoofed and taken into account? Whats to stop me from choosing the most common device fingerprints and switching between them?

Answer (score 1):

MAC address can be changed in software. Hostnames can also be changed in software. If the host runs multi-boot OS's, then the OS details, ports/services, and even the characteristics of how the machine uses WiFi will change.

There has been research into the unique qualities of WiFi radio transmitters, but you need special equipment.

If you own and control the networks you could issue client certificates and that makes it possible to track devices in a way that users cannot interfere with.

Comment: OP clarified that they are interested in avoiding identification; perhaps you could tailor your answer more towards that?
I am also curious about this ever since p-droid died.